# Как установить порт для домена Apache2 на Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

На сервере установлена Ubuntu 18.04 + Apache2.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы если захожу, например, на сайт **example.com:5145**, то открывался проект номер 1, а если захожу на **example.com**, то открывался проект номер 2.

Как можно получить такое?

Comment: Добавьте в конфиге новую секцию `VirtualHost` в которой сделайте нужные изменения, но при указании `ServerName` порт не используйте.

Comment: Спасибо большое получился